# Create class based on identifier

Tags: c#, class, oop

Right now I have the following function which doesn't look really nice to me:

```
string input = "??";
Letter output = null;

switch(input[0])
{
    case LetterA.Id: // = 'A'
        output = new LetterA();
        break;

    case LetterB.Id: // = 'B'
        output = new LetterB();
        break;

    case LetterC.Id: // = 'C'
        output = new LetterC();
        break;

    // ...
}

if (output == null)
    throw new Exception();

output.Parse(input);

return output;
```

Is there a better/shorter way to solve this problem and to create classes based on an Identifier?

Comment: read about Factory pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got will work, and it's not uncommon.

Another option is to create a dictionary that maps the Id string to a delegate that returns a Letter or a dictionary that maps the Id to an object that derives from Letter, from which a clone can be made (that choice might depend on whether the different derived Letter classes have different construction parameters).

```
//example of second

Dictionary<string, Letter> PrototypeLetters = new Dictionary<string, Letter>();

//...
output = PrototypeLetters[input]->MakeClone();
//where make clone is virtual in Letter returning a Letter (of derived type as Letter)
//still need to handle case where input is not found
```

On the downside you have to build that map, building it at runtime is more flexible if you ever need to vary the behaviour, but that includes the flexibility to introduce bugs, and makes unit testing less easy.

On the plus side the code that gets the Letter from the Id doesn't have to know about every derived Letter type.

Whether you think that option is better depends on what criteria you compare the options.

Comment: Rather than an object to clone, I'd go with a delegate that creates an object of that type.

Comment: Yes, the delegate was the first of my 2 suggestions. I think it'd be more efficient for the cases where all derived typed are constructed with the same parameters - but clone option doesn't require that.

Comment: I already thought about using Dictonarys, but i haven't thought about delegates. I like that idea - so i don't have to create an instance of the object first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection. The following assumes that `Letter`, `LetterA`, `LetterB`, and so on all live in the same assembly.

```
var letterType = typeof(Letter).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Name == "Letter" + input[0]);
var output = Activator.CreateInstance(letterType) as Letter;
```

Please note that the above should have some error checking added to it in case the type cannot be found or cannot be cast to a `Letter` after instantiation.

Comment: Defer usage for reflection as long as there is a "better" way or workaround.

Comment: @nikhilvartak: "better" is very subjective. If this is some kind of plug-in architecture then constantly change a `switch` statement inside a factory is a royal PITA. "Reflection is slow", which I'm sure will be your response, is a myth that developers have been parroting for years. Yes, if you're writing a real-time system or a game then it's probably not appropriate, but for the vast majority of business/commercial applications your database accesses are far slower than a little bit of reflection.